# Migration to Data API GA4

Tags: google-analytics, google-analytics-api, google-analytics-4

In Analytics Reporting API V4 we had following dimensions:

```
ga:keyword (utm_term) https://ga-dev-tools.google/dimensions-metrics-explorer/traffic-sources/#keyword
ga:adContent (utm_content) https://ga-dev-tools.google/dimensions-metrics-explorer/traffic-sources/#adContent
ga:medium (utm_medium) https://ga-dev-tools.google/dimensions-metrics-explorer/traffic-sources#medium
ga:source (utm_source) https://ga-dev-tools.google/dimensions-metrics-explorer/traffic-sources#source
ga:campaign (utm_campaign) https://ga-dev-tools.google/dimensions-metrics-explorer/traffic-sources#campaign
```

Now we all need to switch to Google Analytics Data API (GA4). I found these metrics:

```
ga:campaign = sessionCampaignName   
ga:source  = sessionSource
ga:medium = sessionMedium
ga:adContent = sessionManualAdContent
ga:keyword = sessionManualTerm
```

Did I make it right? Because I also found metrics like: `campaignName, source, medium, manualAdContent, manualTerm`.

Also I want to ask about **Multi-Channel Funnels Reporting API**. How can I get data specified in this API with new GA4 API? Is it this https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/reporting/data/v1/rest/v1alpha/properties/runFunnelReport? It looks like kinda diffrent.